# Setting order of a SubView with monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have created a viewcontroller and have added some labels and a button to the view using the interface builder.

I am trying to add a rounded white border to the view so I am building a view via code using

```
//http://spazzarama.com/2011/01/08/monotouch-uiview-with-curved-border-and-shadow/
public class WhiteRectangle:UIView
{
    // Constructor used when view is defined in InterfaceBuilder
    public WhiteRectangle (IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        this.CreateCurveAndShadow();
    }

    // Constructor to use when creating in code
    public WhiteRectangle (System.Drawing.RectangleF frame) : base(frame)
    {
        this.CreateCurveAndShadow();
    }

    private void CreateCurveAndShadow()
    {
        // MasksToBounds == false allows the shadow to appear outside the UIView frame
        this.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
        this.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;
        this.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.DarkGray.CGColor;
        this.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 1.0f;
        this.Layer.ShadowRadius = 6.0f;
        this.Layer.ShadowOffset = new System.Drawing.SizeF(0f, 3f);
    }


}
```

Within my ViewControllers ViewDidLoad

```
        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        var view = new WhiteRectangle(new System.Drawing.RectangleF(10, 10, 300, 300));
        view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        View.AddSubview (view);
    }
```

Now my problem is the view I am creating as you would expect is being added after the view created in the interface builder. Is it possible to set the order of the view?

I have tried

```
    View.Subviews[0].SendSubviewToBack(View.Subviews[1]);
    View.Subviews[1].SendSubviewToBack(View.Subviews[0]);
```

Neither work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was close. If anyone else is stuck on the same thing this worked

```
this.View.BringSubviewToFront(View.Subviews[0]);
```